# Copy current cell to specific cell in other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've used the record macro function to generate the following script.
I want the content of **any active cell** to be copy-pasted over to cell 'E2' in another sheet 'facture'. But I don't want `getRange('\'orders/sales\'!C29')`. What should it be?

```
function invoice() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('facture'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'orders/sales\'!C29').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

(PS: I'm not a coder. Saw a few topics on the matter but all too complexe, hence my basic question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this code into your code editor and restart your Google Sheet document

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Admin Menu')
        .addItem('Copy Active Cell', 'copyActiveCellValue')
        .addItem('First Run - authorization', 'firstRun')
        .addToUi();
}

function firstRun(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Autorization completed! You can use your script now.');
}


function copyActiveCellValue() {
  var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currentCellValue = spreadsheetDocument.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  var spreadsheet2 = spreadsheetDocument.getSheetByName('facture').activate();
spreadsheet2.getRange(2,5).setValue(currentCellValue).activateAsCurrentCell();
}
```

After that, wait for "Admin Menu" to load in beside "Help", press "First Run" and approve authorization. After that, when you click on "Copy Active Cell" you will get value from active cell in the "E2" field on 'facture' sheet.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! How to make sure the 'facture' tab becomes active for user's viewing?

Comment: You can just add activate() on the spreadsheet2, so the line look like var spreadsheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('facture').activate();

Comment: For case that you want 'E2' to be selected after script execution, switch last line to spreadsheet2.getRange(2,5).setValue(currentCellValue).activateAsCurrentCell();